# BlackJack window program wont show up

Tags: java, jframe, actionlistener, blackjack

I have assigned to write a basic BlackJack Window Program using JFrame and card images provided by my teacher. I wrote everything out from what I think should work however it doesn't show up at all when I compile it. Is am I missing something?

When I compile the program it successfully compiles, however, after I execute the file in my library BlackJack.java, nothing executes and my program does not show up. In the command prompt, it shows it executed but no BlackJack/JFrame shows up on the screen.

I have tried adjusting the BlackJack Classes and MyJFrame classes so the JFrame executes right away, however it doesn't seem to be working.
And in a previous assignment, we were required to write a JFrame for this BlackJack class, mine worked just fine. So I feel like the BlackJack implements are causing issues.

**Note:We are given a java file called DeckOfCards and gif files for card images to use**

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*; 
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Vector;
public class BlackJack extends JFrame implements ActionListener
{
private JLabel[] lblPlayer = new JLabel[8];
private JLabel[] lblDealer = new JLabel[8];

private JPanel pnlPlayDeal = new JPanel(new GridLayout(2,8)); 

private DeckOfCards deck = new DeckOfCards();

private Vector <String> playerCardNames = new Vector<String>();
private Vector <String> dealerCardNames = new Vector<String>();

private ImageIcon[] icoPlayerHand = new ImageIcon[8];
private ImageIcon[] icoDealerHand = new ImageIcon[8];

private JButton btnDeal = new JButton("Deal");
private JButton btnPlayer = new JButton("Player");
private JButton btnDealer = new JButton("Dealer");
private JButton btnNew = new JButton("New");
private JButton btnAuthor = new JButton("Author");

private JPanel pnlButtons = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());

private int count = 1;
private int playerval = 0;
private int dealerval = 0;

public void MyJFrame()
{
    for(int i=0;i<8;i++)
    {
        lblPlayer[i] = new JLabel("Player");
        lblDealer[i] = new JLabel("Dealer");
    }
    this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    this.setSize(800, 350);
    this.setVisible(true);   
    add(pnlPlayDeal,BorderLayout.CENTER);
    add(pnlButtons,BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    this.addLabels();
    this.addButtons();
    registerListeners();
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
}    
public void addLabels()
{
    for(int i= 0;i<8;i++)
    {
        pnlPlayDeal.add(lblPlayer[i]);
    }
    for(int i= 0;i<8;i++)
    pnlPlayDeal.add(lblDealer[i]);        
}    
public void addButtons()
{
    pnlButtons.add(btnDeal);
    pnlButtons.add(btnPlayer);
    btnPlayer.setEnabled(false);
    pnlButtons.add(btnDealer);
    btnDealer.setEnabled(false);
    pnlButtons.add(btnNew);
    btnNew.setEnabled(false);
    pnlButtons.add(btnAuthor);
}    
public void registerListeners()
{
    btnDeal.addActionListener(this);
    btnPlayer.addActionListener(this);
    btnDealer.addActionListener(this);
    btnNew.addActionListener(this);
    btnAuthor.addActionListener(this);
}    
public int findRank(String x)
{
    int result=0;
    if(x.startsWith("Two"))
       result=2;
    else if(x.startsWith("Three"))
       result=3;
    else if(x.startsWith("Four"))
        result=4;
    else if(x.startsWith("Five"))
        result=5;
    else if(x.startsWith("Six"))
        result=6;
    else if(x.startsWith("Seven"))
        result=7;
    else if(x.startsWith("Eight"))
        result=8;
    else if(x.startsWith("Nine"))
        result=9;
    else if(x.startsWith("Ten"))
        result=10;
    else if(x.startsWith("Jack"))
        result=10;
    else if(x.startsWith("Queen"))
        result=10;
    else if(x.startsWith("King"))
        result=10;
    else if(x.startsWith("Ace"))
        result=11;
    return result;
}
public int getVal (Vector<String> v)
{
    int total=0;
    Iterator <String> iter = v.iterator();
    while(iter.hasNext())
    {
        total+= findRank(iter.next());
    }
    return total;
}
public void deal()
{
    deck.shuffle();
    playerCardNames.add(deck.deal());
    playerCardNames.add(deck.deal());
    dealerCardNames.add(deck.deal());
    dealerCardNames.add(deck.deal());

    icoPlayerHand[0] = new ImageIcon("cardImages/"
            +playerCardNames.get(0)+".gif");
    icoPlayerHand[1] = new ImageIcon("cardImages/"
            +playerCardNames.get(1)+".gif");
    lblPlayer[0].setIcon(icoPlayerHand[0]);
    lblPlayer[1].setIcon(icoPlayerHand[1]);

    icoDealerHand[0] = new ImageIcon("cardImages/"+
            dealerCardNames.get(0)+".gif");
    icoDealerHand[1] = new ImageIcon("cardImages/card.gif");
    lblDealer[0].setIcon(icoDealerHand[0]);
    lblDealer[1].setIcon(new ImageIcon("cardImages/card.gif"));

    btnDeal.setEnabled(false);
    btnPlayer.setEnabled(true);
    count ++;
}    
public void player()
{
    while(getVal(playerCardNames)<22)
    {
        String choice = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "you have " 
                +getVal(playerCardNames)+" h/s",null);
        if(choice.equalsIgnoreCase("h"))
        {
            playerCardNames.add(deck.deal());
            icoPlayerHand[count] = new ImageIcon("cardImages/"
                    +playerCardNames.lastElement()+".gif");
            lblPlayer[count].setIcon(icoPlayerHand[count]);
            count++;
        }
        else
        break;
    }
    if(getVal(playerCardNames)>21)
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "You Busted");
        btnPlayer.setEnabled(false);
        btnNew.setEnabled(true);
    }
    else
    {
        btnPlayer.setEnabled(false);
        btnDealer.setEnabled(true);
    }
}      
public void dealer()
{
    btnDealer.setEnabled(false);
    count=1;
    icoDealerHand[count] = new ImageIcon("cardImages/" 
             +dealerCardNames.lastElement()+".gif");
    lblDealer[1].setIcon(icoDealerHand[count]);
    count ++;
    while(getVal(dealerCardNames)<17)
    {
        dealerCardNames.add(deck.deal());
        icoDealerHand[count] = new ImageIcon("cardImages/" 
                +dealerCardNames.lastElement()+".gif");
        lblDealer[count].setIcon(icoDealerHand[count]);
        count ++;
    }
    if(getVal(dealerCardNames)>21)
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Dealer bust you won");
    else
    whoWon();
    btnNew.setEnabled(true);
}            
public void whoWon()
{
    if(getVal(playerCardNames)>getVal(dealerCardNames))
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"You won");
    else
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"You lost");
}    
public void newGame()
{
    this.setVisible(false);
    BlackJack game = new BlackJack();
}
public static void main(String[]args)
{
    MyJFrame table= new MyJFrame();
    BlackJack first = new BlackJack();
}
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{
    if(e.getSource()==btnAuthor)
        ((JButton)e.getSource()).setText("Conner M");
    if(e.getSource()==btnDeal)
        deal();
    if(e.getSource()==btnPlayer)
        player();
    if(e.getSource()==btnDealer)
        dealer();
    if(e.getSource()==btnNew)
    {
        newGame();             
    }        
}
}
```

Comment: Hi Conner, welcome to StackOverflow. Your question doesn't have the right information for us to help you. e.g. We don't know what "it doesn't show up at all when I compile it" means, and you haven't told us what *you've* done to try and solve the problem so far. Have a read of http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, and then update your question with: **What you're trying to achieve, What you've tried to do to solve it, How you know that it's not working.**

Comment: Simplify your example to where you are just trying to show a JFrame.  Once you have that working, add more layers of functionality back in.  You can find simple of examples of displaying JFrames on the web, such as this: http://alvinalexander.com/java/jframe-example  Notice when you setVisible(true) and when and where the examples set it.

Comment: Please look at some [debugging tips](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) that can help you here.  If it brings up a specific problem that you're not sure about, then feel free to come back ask about that problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A. Analysis:

Lets start executing your code manually, your code's starting point is static void main where I can see MyFrame's object is being initialized. Then BlackJack's object is being initialized.

B. The problem:

1. There is no MyFrame class you have declared in your code.
2. Blackjack extends JFrame, so you need to set its reference visible via setVisible() method that is done in the MyJFrame() method (and not in BlackJack's constructor).
3. The method, `newGame()` is again creating a new BlackJack object, but you have not created your own constructor for that. I believe the method MyJFrame should be converted to BlackJack constructor.

C. Probable Solution:

1. Remove  `MyJFrame table= new MyJFrame();`from static void main()
2. Convert method `void MyJFrame()` to BlackJack's constructor
3. Instead of creating a local BlackJack variable 'first' in your main() method, make it a class member (declare it outside of main()) and initialize it in main().
4. As BlackJack's variable is a class member now, in the method `newGame()`, instead of creating a new local variable 'first', do this instead: `first = new BlackJack();`

Note: Your code may have more bugs. The above solution may solve your problem for why it was not displaying the frame. There are more than 1 ways of correcting it, I have only provided the best way possible for now.